# search DNS order

Tags: vbscript, dns, wmi

i need to make validation of dns remotely through multiple pc and i have created the code but the output still show wrong because of the dns order that i have set is not in correctly order.But i want to valid the dns without checking the order just through dns only. im a beginner in this field hope u guys can help thank u so much :-)
below are the code

```
strCompName = "site A", "site B", "site C"

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strCompName & "\root\cimv2")
Set config = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")

'this is fix dns that is set up to valid with old dns
New_dns = Array ("1.1.1.1",_
                  "2.2.2.2",_
                  "3.3.3.3)

For Each conf In config

        If Not IsNull(conf.DNSServerSearchOrder) Then
            For Each strDNSServer In conf.DNSServerSearchOrder

                ' in this code i want to valid the existing dns in pc with dns that is set up

                If strDNSServer = New_dns(number) Then
                    wscript.echo "CORRECT!     " + strDNSServer
                Else
                    wscript.echo "WRONG!       " + strDNSServer
                End If

            Next
        End If

Next
```

Comment: Your first line is wrong and not legal syntax. You would have got a message saying *Expected end of statement*. Only one thing can be assigned to a string.

Comment: im so sorry for that careless mistake

Comment: how to correct the code?

Comment: Use the `Array` function on line 1. Then a `for - each` loop around the rest of your code.

Comment: owh i see... thanks noodles.. i have tried to change the code now what i want to know is it possible that i want to valid the dns without looking the order of dns that i set up in array.. like example if my dns in pc now
1.1.1.1
3.3.3.3
2.2.2.2 
when the code is run in the my pc and the output say that the dns is correct even the order dns not exactly what i set up in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of works. Here is Help for VBS https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764 and for WMI https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx.

Note you have two DNS servers per computer.

```
Dim Computers(2)
Computers(0) = "127.0.0.1"
Computers(1) = "127.0.0.1"
Computers(2) = "127.0.0.1"


For each strcomputer in Computers

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strcomputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set config = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True")

    'this is fix dns that is set up to valid with old dns
    New_dns = Array ("1.1.1.1", "1.1.1.1",_
                      "2.2.2.2", "2.2.2.2",_
                      "192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.1")
    For Each conf In config

            If Not IsNull(conf.DNSServerSearchOrder) Then
                For Each strDNSServer In conf.DNSServerSearchOrder

                    ' in this code i want to valid the existing dns in pc with dns that is set up
    msgbox New_dns(number)
                    If strDNSServer = New_dns(number) Then
                        wscript.echo "CORRECT!     " + strDNSServer
                    Else
                        wscript.echo "WRONG!       " + strDNSServer
                    End If
            number=number+1
                Next
            End If

    Next
Next
```